# ejecutar consulta mysql una a la vez

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un sistema para restaurantes en el cual los meceros generan pedidos y estos pedidos se descuentan al stock de los platos
yo e tenido problemas cuando por ejemplo 2 o 3 meceros ingresan su pedido al mismo tiempo (hosting) para descontar uso el siguiente codigo (ejemplo):

```
update platos set stock = stock-1 where plato = $plato;
```

el problema de este codigo es que por ejemplo un mecero puede ingresar varios platos por pedido y tengo que usar un update por cada plato.
La pregunta es: existe algun codigo que ponga en espera al otro usuario que quiere consultar (update) la base de datos hasta que este termine su consulta por orden de llegada ?
de antemano gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Hola, yo personalmente no tengo una respuesta, o código, exacto para tu problema, pero, te digo que lo necesitas implementar es, un sistema de colas, para aplazar tareas y ejecutar en segundo plano. Como lo hace *Laravel* con *Redis* por ejemplo, te recomiendo que le eches un ojo a eso

Comment: @JosbertMuria si o si necesito usar framework ? no habra una gestion con php puro ?

Comment: No es necesario un framework sino quieres, pero si te facilitaría mucho estas cosas, y por supuesto que puedes configurar una cola de trabajos con *PHP* puro, puedes implementarla por ejemplo, con *Redis* como te digo, o incluso con una base datos SQL y usar un worker para observar las tareas en cola

Comment: Tal vez sea algo que requiera un poco de trabajo, pero si que es muy posible